# Gradient texture from color into transparency incorrectly turns into black

Tags: texturing, uv, transparency

Basically I have a texture with transparent background applied to my model. Thats my setup:

[image: setup2]

As you can see  the part of the wheel that is meant to be "a highlight" unfortunately has black stripes instead of being transparent.

Here is how in looks in photoshop.

[image: ps]

How can I make transparency work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to plug the alpha output channel of your *Image Texture* into the alpha input of a *Principled BSDF* for example:

[image]

Also, don't forget to choose *Alpha Blend* in the *Material > Settings > Blend Mode*.

Comment: I've followed the instructions however now the wheel sides are almost fully transparent and whole model is affected by lights
but yeah - highlights are now showing without black color

Comment: make sure that the wheel sides UVs lay over the color you want, not over a transparent part of your image, or assign them another material

Comment: yeah I have highlight as a separate mesh few pixels above the wheel. I have separated materials and it helped but only a bit. There are no hard black lines however now it blends with black color https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dy3Oo.png

Comment: I'm not sure what's your problem, maybe edit your question and give a link to your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/ don't forget to pack the image before sharing

Comment: my bad
I've connected color to alpha. Fixed it and now everything works fine. Thank you!